# How to encode the video file using HM encoder by running and debugging without going to command prompt

Tags: video-streaming, video-processing, video-encoding, hevc, h.265

I am new to HM encoder. I rebuild and debug the encoder in MS VISUAL STUDIO EXPRESS 2013. I kept the input file and the configuration file in the same folder where TAppEncoder.exe lies. To encode the input video file then i have to go to command prompt and then i have to type commands as inputs in it. But what i want is to rebuild and debug and get the encoded version of the video file without going to command prompt. Can this be possible?    THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a generic feature of MS VS or MS VC and has nothing to do with H.265 or HM. 
After building the HM application, just do `Ctrl+F5` to run the built application without debugging i.e. stepping into it.
If you want to debug, you can do F5 to step into the code.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to project properties -> Configuration Properties->Debugging in that command argument type your input path and output file path with correct option.